# how to avoid to use pip install -e <submodule> everytime I git pull updates in <submodule>?

Tags: python-3.x, git-submodules, python-packaging

I use Python 3.6 in my project.

My git repository contains a submodule that needs to be installed as a library for the project. To be able to make changes in this library, I install it in *editable* mode, that is with: `pip install -e.`

But when I `git pull` the last modifications of this submodule, I need to install the library again, even if it was previously installed in editable mode.

Is there any way to install this library to avoid this problem (i.e. reinstall it every time after a pull) ?